# pandas isin comparison to multiple columns, not including index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to test whether a dictionary of key-value pairs is contained in a DataFrame with columns having the same names as the dictionary.

*example:*

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [2,8,4,9,6], 'B': [7,1,8,3,5], 'C': [8,4,9,1,6], 'D': [7,8,9,1,2], 'E': [3,8,4,9,6]})

df1
    
    A   B   C   D   E
0   2   7   8   7   3
1   8   1   4   8   8
2   4   8   9   9   4
3   9   3   1   1   9
4   6   5   6   2   6

d = {'A': 9, 'B': 3, 'C': 1, 'D': 1, 'E': 9}

df2 = pd.DataFrame([d])

df2

    A   B   C   D   E
0   9   3   1   1   9
```

What I want is a statement that returns True if the entire row of values in df2 is matched anywhere in df1. I've tried passing d and df2 to the .isin values parameter:

```
df1.isin(d)
```

results in an error.

```
TypeError: only list-like or dict-like objects are allowed to be passed to DataFrame.isin(), you passed a 'int'
```

while using df2 returns all False.

```
df1.isin(df2)

    A       B       C       D       E
0   False   False   False   False   False
1   False   False   False   False   False
2   False   False   False   False   False
3   False   False   False   False   False
4   False   False   False   False   False
```

I played around with the last example in the [pandas.DataFrame.isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) doc, and realized my test with df2 fails because the index doesn't match (3 in df1 versus 0 in df2).

Is there an easy way to do this with isin that ignores the index, or some other method that doesn't involve stringing together five equality tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you expect?

```
>>> df1.eq(df2.values).all(axis=1).any()
True
```

You can also use `d` directly:

```
>>> df1.eq(d).all(axis=1).any()
True
```

Comment: Yes, thanks very much! I knew there must be a simple answer. If I add .any() to the end, that will give me a single Boolean, right?

Comment: FYI, confirmed that adding .any() to the end makes it a T/F statement:
`df1.eq(df2.values).all(axis=1).any()`
`True`